# UIPanGestureRecognizer stateEnded in a CustomCell class notifies MainViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My apps **MainViewController** uses a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCells` from **CustomCell**. With `UIPanGestureRecognizer` the user can slide a cell left or right. After the slide, the `textLabel.text` and slide direction are stored to `static NSStrings`.

The animation code is **CustomCell** and works fine.

### How could **MainViewController** know or be notified when CustomCell's `recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`?

---

**CustomCell**

```
static NSString *cellAction = NULL; // textLabel.text

static NSString *slideTo = NULL; // slide direction
-(id)initWithStyle{

    UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];

    [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

}
```

---

**MainViewController**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

   actionTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];

   [self.view addSubview:middleActionTable];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

   CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident forIndexPath:indexPath];

   return cell;
}
```

---

After this works I plan on using the 2 static strings from **CustomCell** to perform a modal segue from **MainViewController** to **AnotherViewController**. I only need the 2 strings after the slide action.

Comment: You have been on SO for quite long. It'd help everyone if you can use proper formatting for your questions (something similar to the way I have edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code

```
UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];

[self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

right after you create the cell in your MainViewController like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

     CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident forIndexPath:indexPath];

     //more of your existing code here

     UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];

     [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
     return cell;
}
```

And move your handlePan: method to the MainViewController.

Unless there's a strong reason for you to have the handlePan: method in the cell class, its best to add have it in the MainViewController (if you want to avoid creating/setting a delegate or using blocks)

Comment: I've tried this. It's a lot to move over, and will be done as a last result. Plus this doesn't allow the tableview to scroll anymore, why is that? Could you go further into detail of using a delegate or blocks.

Comment: there are a lot of great answers for "setting a delegate", "setting a delegate on UITableViewCell". here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062572/adding-a-delegate-to-a-custom-uitableviewcell-bad-access-error